# Reactjs: Regarding form submission

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a simple subscribe form which has two input email and interest. After submission user receives a thank you message in place of the form. My question is should I use "Route" to achieve that functionality or is there any better way.

First screen

[image]

Afte submitting form

[image]

Is there any better approach to switch component on form submission.
Can someone point me in the right direction ROUTE or conditional switch component.

Comment: Both are valid options. Hard to tell without looking at your code. I guess you should go with what is easier for you

Comment: @klugjo generally asking as per better option as route is remaining the same only component is changing right. I dont need help with the code instead right direction..

Comment: Do you already have react router setup and working ? If yes then route might be a decent options. Where does the data come from ? Redux ? It is hard to give the right direction without more info on your current architecture

Comment: @klugjo Its a simple react app no need for redux. I am testing with router as well. My question is What will be the path as my form is in home page n then again i should use same home path as it is just a footer subscribe feature dont want to change the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you take approach of component(izing) your react application, ideally your above FORM component should handle all scenarios e.g. showing initial form view, error handling, and successful form submission etc. cases conditionally.

Comment: hi, so i should check all these 3 conditions in my form component no need to create a new one right?